# How to implement code for Dev and Staging in cucumber framework

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am testing at work Dev and Staging environments. Data in Dev and Staging is different and also I do not have to verify DB in backend when I am testing Staging. How can I apply code with different condition in my framework? I was trying to use if condition
For example driver.getCurentURL and if URL == Dev --> do this, else --> Do this.
But for some reason if statement doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Generally speaking you wouldn't rely on the data that is already there. You'd created it as part of the given and when step in your scenario. Other then that this isn't a question any one can help you answer. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Working with multiple/different environments is common aspect while you are testing. In order to support different environments you need to follow some standard practice while implementing test case and/or step.

- Do not hard code test data, and move it into properties
- Provide support to Load environment specific resources and test data at the time of execution
- Regarding variation in step, step implementation are different then those can be moved to separate package and step should be loaded from appropriate package at the time of run. In case of minor difference, you can add condition in your code.

For example:

```
public void doCheckOut(){
    //fill Credit Card Details
    //credit card details will be provided in properties and that will be loaded for environment by resource manager
    sendKeys(getBundle().getString("cc.number"),"input.ccnumber.loc");
    ...
    if(getBundle().getString("env.name").equalsIgnoreCase("dev"){
        //only run for dev env
         click_checkOutBtn();
    }
}
```

You can use [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#using-qaf-cucumber-with-cucumber-runner) for [resource management](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html) capability.

If you want to skip entire step for specific environment, AFAIK
when using cucumber runner, you can't do that. However when using qaf with cucumber runner if you have created step using [qaf step implementation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/Describe_Test_Step.html) (or using TestNG instead of cucumber), you can utilize [step listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#teststep-listener) along with [step meta-data](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/Test_Step_Metadata.html) to skip entire step for specific environment.

Comment: Thank you guys. Already figured out how to handle that part.